# JavaScript: Is it possible to scrollspy on an iFrame's parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm having a parallax effect inside an iFrame. Because I'd like to avoid double scroll bars, the iFrame is automatically resized to it's actual height.

However, the parallax won't work anymore, because the `$(window).scrollTop()` will always be `0` inside the iFrame.

Is it possible to scrollspy on an iFrame's parent?

Here is a very simplified snippet:
Inside the iFrame is a script which needs to get the `.scrollTop()` of `$('.get-scroll')`

```
<body class="get-scroll">
   <div class="stuff">
      ...
   </div>
   <iframe>
      <script>
         //do some magic
      </script>
   </iframe>
   <div class="other-stuff">
      ...
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(window.parent.window).scrollTop()` to get the iframe's parent scroll.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/nmvnshdg/) for an example. *(I couldn't do it in a Stack Overflow snippet)*